# How to create a dynamic table in the administration panel of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to create a table in the wordpress admin panel that reads dynamic data from the database and that can manage this data from there.

For example: As the wordpress user management table, I attach an image -> https://prnt.sc/1xuxks2

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you made any attempts at anything yet? If so post what you've tried. Probably need to search for wordpress admin tutorials

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Create admin page using add_menu_page and hook it to admin_menu then in your content function pull your data as query for example. Filters are working with your query or other queries. Thats all. Use codex and google :)